# What do I need to do to move in with a friend and his family in another country?

Tags: usa, uk

I live in the United States and my friend lives over in England with his family. There's a very good chance that I'm going to be living with them somewhere down the line. I'll be working for my friend's father along with my friend.

What kind of visa would I need?

This would most definitely be more than a 6 month stay and such. I don't exactly know where to begin.

What preparations (paperwork-wise) would I need, like a passport and such?

Edit: Migrated.

https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7017/what-do-i-need-to-do-to-move-in-with-a-friend-and-his-family-in-another-country

Comment: This should probably be migrated to expats.